# Error when running tests with nose-gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nose, nose-gae

I've been using nose-gae for awhile, and I just updated to release 0.3.0, which is only 3 days old.  I'm running GAE SDK 1.9.17 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

When I run my tests, I get the following error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
>   can't open file
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/_python_runtime.py':
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Sure enough, that file doesn't exist.  My tests appear to run successfully however (test output below).  I don't see any such errors when running the dev_appserver.

I don't know what `_python_runtime.py` is and what is causing the error.  Any help figuring out what is going on would be appreciated.

====

```
$ nosetests -x tests/functional_tests.py
................/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/_python_runtime.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 19 tests in 11.032s

OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module `_python_runtime.py` should be in the SDK root folder. (confirmation here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/)

Are you sure that it is included in your PATH? If yes -- it is best to fill an issue [here](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE/issues), such nose-gae still buggy after update.

**UPDATE** this issue is solved with latest NoseGAE update, which is currently in dev branch [here](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE/tree/0_4_0_dev). Just clone it and use `sudo python setup.py install` to update it.

Comment: Thanks, I filed an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that nose-gae uses the old devappserver rather than the newer one.  The old devappserver was removed from the SDK in 1.9.17.

Comment: I don't think so.  That is what motivated me to upgrade to the latest release of nose-gae.  The previous version gave the error `ImportError: cannot import name old_dev_appserver` and this one doesn't have that error.

Comment: Good to hear that Nose has been updated to use the new dev_appserver now.